# TSconfig: compile a new js folder for each ts folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, tsconfig

**I want to compile a new js folder for each script folder. Is that possible with `tsconfig.json`?**

*Directories*

```
folder1
  scripts
    index.ts

folder2
  scripts
   index.ts
tsconfig.json
```

*Directories after compile*

```
folder1
  scripts
    index.ts
  js
    index.js

folder2
  scripts
    index.ts
  js
    index.js
tsconfig.json
```

Comment: For now I'm using a `tsconfig.json` file for each directory... EDIT: no that didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer... this doesn't answer your question specifically, because what you want to do breaks with convention. Even if you manage to do it your way, I think you'll find the pain will outweigh the benefit.

The simplest way is to specify an `outDir` output directory. Your existing folder structure will be maintained in the output directory, with all the JavaScript and TypeScript kept cleanly separated.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./scripts",
        ...
    }
}
```

So if you start with:

```
/component-a
    index.ts
/component-b
    index.ts
```

You'll end up with the folders mirrored in the output directory.

```
/component-a
    index.ts
/component-b
    index.ts
/scripts
    /component-a
        index.js
    /component-b
        index.js
```

Unless you plan to deploy both (?) you don't normally want the TypeScript and JavaScript intermingled.

Comment: Is there a way to not get `scripts` folder in my `js` folder. When I compile it looks like this: `/js/folder1/scripts/index.js`;
I want it to look like this: `/js/folder1/index.js`;